# user agent style sheet override my css

Tags: css, header, doctype

I want to add a css for the select option disabled.

But my browser compile the user agent stylesheet and not my new css.
I read that i must be carreful with the doctype. but it seems to be write good.

This is my header

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="description" content="">

    <meta name="author" content="xxxxxx">


    <link href="/Content/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <link href="/Content/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>xxxxxx</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/Bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


</head>
```

And my new css

```
select option:disabled {
   color:#c09853 !important;
   background-color: #fcf8e3 !important;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

This is my compilate CSS on a disabled select option. 
It seems that my new css is not loaded

```
element.style {
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
user agent stylesheet
input[type="button" i]:disabled, input[type="submit" i]:disabled, input[type="reset" i]:disabled, input[type="file" i]:disabled::-webkit-file-upload-button, button:disabled, select:disabled, keygen:disabled, optgroup:disabled, option:disabled, select[disabled] > option {
    color: graytext;
}
user agent stylesheet
option {
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
    min-height: 1.2em;
    padding: 0px 2px 1px;
}
Inherited from select#lst_5__courtId.input-lg.selectCourtId
select.input-lg {
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 45px;
}
.input-lg {
    height: 45px;
    padding: 10px 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.33;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
input, button, select, textarea {
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
}
user agent stylesheet
select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: pre;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: default;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, keygen, select, button {
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: initial;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
    font: 12.6667px Arial;
}
user agent stylesheet
input, textarea, keygen, select, button, meter, progress {
    -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
Inherited from table.table-hover.table-bordered.table-striped
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
user agent stylesheet
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: grey;
}
Inherited from body
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
Inherited from html.js.flexbox.flexboxlegacy.canvas.canvastext.webgl.touch.geolocation.postmessage.websqldatabase.indexeddb.hashchange.history.draganddrop.websockets.rgba.hsla.multiplebgs.backgroundsize.borderimage.borderradius.boxshadow.textshadow.opacity.cssanimations.csscolumns.cssgradients.cssreflections.csstransforms.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.fontface.generatedcontent.video.audio.localstorage.sessionstorage.webworkers.applicationcache.svg.inlinesvg.smil.svgclippaths
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
Pseudo ::before element
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
Pseudo ::after element
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS has to be mention last, after all the other CSS. Otherwise they will overwrite your CSS. Not sure were your CSS is placed in the HTML.

Comment: Verify your path, and put only your css link inside the head tag to test it.

Comment: Thanks, I added my CSS at the end of bootstrap.css stylesheet

Comment: Edit : Add the compilated CSS on the select option